# register DbContext service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I was reading a book and get confused with Repository, below is the code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
   public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options) { }

   public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
   private ApplicationDbContext context;

   public EFProductRepository(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
   {
      context = ctx;
   }

   public IQueryable<Product> Products => context.Products;
}
```

and the startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:SportStoreProducts:ConnectionString"]));

   services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();
}
```

so my questions are:

Q1-I understand that `services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();` repository service so when other part of application needs a `IProductRepository`, a new `EFProductRepository` object will be given. But what about the EFProductRepository's constructor which requires an`ApplicationDbContext` object ctx, don't we need to code sth the same as:

```
services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext, ...>();
```

or the `services.AddDbContext` has the same effect as `services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext, ...>();`

Q2-ApplicationDbContext also has a constructor that requires a `DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>` object options, so how this one get registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your questions are answered by inspecting this line:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:SportStoreProducts:ConnectionString"]));
```

That registers your `ApplicationDbContext` as a transient object with the dependency resolver. This part:

```
options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:SportStoreProducts:ConnectionString"])
```

is creating the `DbContextOptions` object that your DbContext's constructor requires. So, it's not "technically" registered as a resolvable type, but that whole line lets the application know how to create an `ApplicationDbContext` when requested.

Comment: @secondimage No problem. If you need a good resource, I suggest this book, https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns - can probably find it on Amazon or similar for a decent price.

Comment: By the way, just a question, why . AddDbContext register a transient object? Shouldnt it register a singleton object? Since the database configurations such as connection string won't change?

Comment: No. Singleton is actually the worst lifetime/scope for a DbContext. A DbContext should only exist for the lifetime of the task for which it's used; for web applications, that's typically "per-request", meaning the context is created when the request begins and disposed of when the request ends. You have to keep in mind that Entity Framework will (by default) store a snapshot of fetched data in it's cache when any query is run. That means it becomes stale pretty quickly, if you're making changes.

Comment: sorry, I'm not very familiar with EF, so why DbContext should be disposed asap? Isn't that EF can created as many as Dbcontexts to serve? Could you give me an example what happen if dbcontext is singleton?

Comment: That's a pretty broad topic to cover. You might want to check out one of the chat rooms, although I don't see one dedicated to Entity Framework. This gets a bit technical, but has some useful info: https://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/